# Count values in column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to count values in a column like this:

```
A
A
B
B
A
A
A
B
B
```

I want it to count the value `A` every time it appears.
Giving a result like this:

```
A = 2
A = 3
```

Comment: Do you want to count only A's like that or even B's and any such other repeating characters in the column?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried lots of Formula but unable to find the exact results, the nearest Formula which I tried was counting correctly except the 3 A's.*

Finally I decided to go with Subtotal since Data Range has already in groups of As nd Bs. And I found the structure stating the correct count.

[image]

**NOte**, as soon you apply Subtotal command Excel will prompt you for the technical mistake, **'since Subtotal needs Numeric Column'** simply hit Ok, in next screen you find Excel automatically picked the **Count for each group**. You finally finish with Ok, you get the same results as the Screen shot looks like.

**Hope you like this idea, in case of either you and any reader finds any formula, just post to help me & others.**